# How to find the missing jar?

Tags: java, windows, build, jar

If I have a project with hundrends of `jar` files, and e.g. I have an `import` of a package that can not be found, how would I find which `jar` should I include?
I.e. how do I know that package `a.b.c` is defined in `X.jar` under `/filesystem/jars` where under this path there are hundrends of `jars`?
Is there e.g. a tool to search inside jars? grep-like for jars?

Comment: Have a look at this answer [find a jar file given the class name][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500141/find-a-jar-file-given-the-class-name

Answer (score 3):

Just google with the class name say "org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages + jar".

You will get the jars which has the respective class.

you can also search in http://www.jarfinder.com.

Comment: This is not a public domain class

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to add  the java option `-verbose:class` to your startup options, this will produce dumps like:

```
[Loaded java.security.BasicPermissionCollection from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.misc.JavaSecurityProtectionDomainAccess from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.security.ProtectionDomain$2 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.security.ProtectionDomain$Key from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.security.Principal from shared objects file]
```

See also [what-is-shared-objects-fil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393940/what-is-shared-objects-file)

I use eclipse with  maven. In this environment I can simply open the class and choose `View in Package Explorer`from the context menu. After that the Package Explorer shows the expanded strcuture of the jar in the Maven Dependcies.